# Client side download of big XML, javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm generating XML-file in javascript. To make it downlodable to the user, I do this:

```
<button href="text/xml;charset=utf-8 <xml data here>" download="myfile.xml">Download</button>
```

It works when the files are small, < 1mb. But crashes when the file gets bigger. Works in firefox but not in Chrome.

Are there any alternate way of doing this? I would like to avoid doing this server-side to save bandwidth and performance.

Comment: You could try using the `Blob` structure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: It works! Generates several mb of xml instantly. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I didn’t use `Blob` myself so far (only indirectly via `File`), but it seemed to match your use case exactly.